# Map JSON to POJO For Processing - Unrecognized field not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I need help in mapping below JSON structure for further processing.

```
    [{
    "userId": "11",
    "otherId": "a",
    "key1": "Tesla",
    "key2": "S3",
    "behaviour": {
        "color": "white",
        "size": "S",
        "owner": "Mr. A"
    }
}, 
{
    "userId": "22",
    "otherId": "",
    "key1": "Merc",
    "key2": "C-Class",
    "behaviour": {
        "color": "black",
        "size": "M",
        "isNew": true
    }
},
{
    "userId": "33",
    "otherId": "c",
    "key1": "Honda",
    "key2": "CRV",
    "behaviour": {
        "color": "green",
        "size": "L",
    }
}]
```

Below is the POJO i have:

```
public class MainObject {
    private String userId;
    private String otherId;
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    private Set<Behaviour> behaviours;
}

public class Behaviour {
    private final String name;
    private final Object value;
}
```

I need to get the list of MainObject for further processing. Tried below but not sure how can i map for behaviour set -

```
String inputLine = currentBufferedReader.readLine();
//Above String has complete JSON

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
FirstObject[] firstObjects = objectMapper.readValue(inputLine, FirstObject[].class);
```

I am getting: Unrecognized field not marked as ignorable with above code. Please suggest.

Comment: You should use _Map<String, Object> behaviour;_

Comment: Mapper can't just map 'color', 'size' or 'owner' to 'name' field of Behaviour class. Mapper assert field has the same name as json field. Try use jackson annotations on class field name to specify additional mapping to this field.

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define ur class like belwo

```
class MainObject {
    public String userId;
    public String otherId;
    public String key1;
    public String key2;
    @JsonProperty(value = "behaviour")
    public Map<String, String> behaviours;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MainObject [userId=" + userId + ", otherId=" + otherId + ", key1=" + key1 + ", key2=" + key2
                + ", behaviours=" + behaviours + "]";
    }
}
```

Code to map

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    String array = "[\r\n" + 
            "   {\r\n" + 
            "      \"userId\":\"11\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"otherId\":\"a\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"key1\":\"Tesla\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"key2\":\"S3\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"behaviour\":{\r\n" + 
            "         \"color\":\"white\",\r\n" + 
            "         \"size\":\"S\",\r\n" + 
            "         \"owner\":\"Mr. A\"\r\n" + 
            "      }\r\n" + 
            "   },\r\n" + 
            "   {\r\n" + 
            "      \"userId\":\"22\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"otherId\":\"\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"key1\":\"Merc\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"key2\":\"C-Class\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"behaviour\":{\r\n" + 
            "         \"color\":\"black\",\r\n" + 
            "         \"size\":\"M\",\r\n" + 
            "         \"isNew\":true\r\n" + 
            "      }\r\n" + 
            "   },\r\n" + 
            "   {\r\n" + 
            "      \"userId\":\"33\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"otherId\":\"c\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"key1\":\"Honda\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"key2\":\"CRV\",\r\n" + 
            "      \"behaviour\":{\r\n" + 
            "         \"color\":\"green\",\r\n" + 
            "         \"size\":\"L\"\r\n" + 
            "      }\r\n" + 
            "   }\r\n" + 
            "]";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MainObject[] objects = mapper.readValue(array, MainObject[].class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(objects));
    
}
```

**output**

```
 [MainObject [userId=11, otherId=a, key1=Tesla, key2=S3, behaviours={color=white, size=S, owner=Mr. A}], 
MainObject [userId=22, otherId=, key1=Merc, key2=C-Class, behaviours={color=black, size=M, isNew=true}],
 MainObject [userId=33, otherId=c, key1=Honda, key2=CRV, behaviours={color=green, size=L}]]
```

Comment: I have posted another question on similar line. Can you please help. I am having little difficulty with map objects - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491039/how-to-process-object-with-map-for-csv-output