# How to process object with map for CSV output

Tags: java, arrays, json, set, export-to-csv

I have a set of below Objects, which i need to write to CSV:

```
public class OutputObject {
    private String userId;
    private Map<String, Object> behaviour;
}
```

Above set can have a map with two, three or four values.

```
[
OutputObject1 [userId=11, behaviours={color=white, size=S, owner=Mr. A}], 
OutputObject2 [userId=22, behaviours={color=black, isNew=true}],
OutputObject3 [userId=33, behaviours={color=green, size=L}]
]
```

Output of CSV required:

```
userId, color, size, owner, isNew
11,     white,  S,   Mr. A,
22,     black,   ,        , true
33,     green,  L,        ,
```

I started with below snippet to print out:

```
     // Set<OutputObject> outputObjectSet already received.
     JSONArray jsonArrayObject = new JSONArray(outputObjectSet);
     String csvValue = CDL.toString(jsonArrayObject);
     FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileObject, true);
     fileWriter.write(csvValue);
     fileWriter.close();
```

But above is creating a two column csv with **userId** and  **behaviours** printing all map object **behaviours**. How to achieve above type of output.

As the set may contain huge number of such objects, how can this be done efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSONArray seems to be redundant here, you could implement a helper method to serialize `OutputObject` into a CSV string, taking into account that the order of the columns needs to be maintained:

```
public class CSVSerializer {
    public static String transform(OutputObject obj) {
        String[] fields = {"color", "size", "owner", "isNew"};
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(obj.getUserId()), 
                Arrays.stream(fields)
                      .map(f -> obj.getBehaviour().get(f))
                      .map(v -> v == null ? "" : v.toString()) 
               )
               .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
}


String csv = outputObjectSet.stream()
                            .map(CSVSerializer::transform)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
// print csv contents
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work pretty efficient, even with a higher number of objects since Java's `HashMap` and `Arrays.sort()` implementations are pretty fast. Note that this implementation relies on Apache's `common-text`-library to escape the contents.

```
private static void outputCSV(List<OutputObject> objects, PrintStream output) {
    AtomicInteger highestBehaviourIndex = new AtomicInteger();

    HashMap<String, Integer> behaviourIndexMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Give every behaviour an index
    for (OutputObject object : objects) {
        object.getBehaviour().forEach((name, value) -> behaviourIndexMap.computeIfAbsent(name, (unused) -> highestBehaviourIndex.getAndIncrement()));
    }

    String[] behaviours = new String[highestBehaviourIndex.get()];

    behaviourIndexMap.forEach((name, index) -> {
        behaviours[index] = name;
    });

    output.println("userId, " + String.join(", ", behaviours));

    // Sort by ID
    objects.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(OutputObject::getUserId));

    for (OutputObject object : objects) {
        // Print line
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
        
        for (String behaviour : behaviours) {
            joiner.add(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(object.getBehaviour().getOrDefault(behaviour, "").toString()));
        }
        
        output.println(object.getUserId() + ", " + joiner.toString());
    }

}
```